# 2D Flash Platformer Game

Tags: game-identification

I want to find the name of the game below and play it. I used to play this flash game about 12-15 years ago. In the game you were controlling the blue ellipse and trying to reach the blue circle. Also, you had to avoid green ellipse to not to die.

Can you identify this game?

[image: theGame]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I was searching my archive, I came across this SWF file. I remember that I saved the game in case of a collapse of the internet :). The name of the game is "Box Clever" and it was made by Gaz Thomas.

[image: Box Clever Level Pack menu screen with plain grey background]

Comment: "I save the game in case of collapse of the internet" LOL

Comment: @pinckerman To be fair, that probably saved the game from Flash support beimg disabled.

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim I wasn't laughing of that statement, it's funny because it's true

Comment: check if its in the flashpoint archive and if not check out on how to get it into the archive. That project (they store the releases at archive.org) works on getting those games to be playable offline.

Comment: @masterX244 Or you could download the standalone Flash Player executable ["flashplayer32.exe"](https://archive.org/details/flashplayer_32_sa_202104) which allows you to run any local .swf you might have downloaded, and even remote ones by providing a full path link in the open menu (doing so will allow you to even play flash contents which require to download subsequent resources on the go).

Comment: Don't suppose you've got Mud and Blood archived?

Comment: @Clockwork Flashpoint is based on that (and they even make sure that the ressources that might be loaded afterwards) are there. they use some proxy magic to fake the internet. I was mainly poking the answerer to check if its already archived there.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater Which one? Mud and Blood 2 or the 3? Or the 1st one?

Comment: Didn't know there was a 2 and 3...